# How to check if a string is already hashed in Node.js using crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, mongoose, password-protection

I am developing an application in which users are allowed o change their passwords.

I am using Node.js with `mongoose` and `crypto`.

In order to generate hashes for the passwords, I've hooked into model's pre('save') event. So basically when you use this:

```
var user = new User({password: '123'});
user.save(); // the password will be encrypted automatically
```

Having the ability to change the password, I need to find a way if the user has actually changed the password or modified any other fields. Example:

```
var user = User.findById('1234567', function(error, user){
     user.name = 'Hello';
     user.save(); // this will hash the password again, although it is not necessary
})
```

I am using Node.js's module called `crypto` to generate hash for passwords:

```
crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 5000, 512, 'sha512', function(error, buffer){

        this.mixins.callback.call(callback, [error, buffer.toString('base64')]);

}.bind(this));
```

**Is there a way to check if the `password` is already a hashed?**
If not, I will generate the hash again.

Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense. You know whether you've got a hash or a password in a variable. If you don't, then no, you don't have any way to distinguish them, a user could always choose a password that looks like a hash.

Comment: I'm using mongoose.js to manage my database models. I am using a hook into pre('save') to change the value of the password to a hashed one. When a model get's saved, I need to know if I should regenerate the hash (because the password changed) or leave it like that because it is already hashed.

Comment: I've updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inherently bad approach. Just call the field `password_hash` and always pass hash explicitly. Otherwise you might accidentally begin to store unhashed password after some minor configuration change.

Also it's generally not possible to distinguish hash from unhashed string if you allow arbitrary strings as passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Hashed string has a hash algorithm identifier prefix. You can validate by checking whether the string is starting with `$2a$` or `$2b$`

[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#hash-info)